# In Excel, Can I Use Formatting to Make a Cell Display the Input as Feet and Inches

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

using excel, I want to be able to enter a number (representing inches) in a cell and have the cell to display it as feet and inches.  For example, if I enter 62 into cell A1, I want cell A1 to display 5' 2".  I know how to use a formula to take the input of one cell and covert it to what I want (i.e., =INT(A1/12)&"'  "&MOD(A1,12)&""""). But I want the converted version to be displayed in the same cell that the input was entered into (i.e., if I enter 62 in cell A1, I want A1 to display 5' 2").  It seems like formatting may be the only way to do this, but I haven't been able to figure out how.  Thanks!

Comment: You would only be able to do that with VBA. You absolutely need a formula to convert the 62" into ft and inches. Formatting alone cannot do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should this be regular or conditional formatting? If regular, then you need to specify the area where you want it to work. If conditional, then you need to specify the triggering condition.
In both cases, you need to use VBA. I'm assuming the first variant (regular formatting) in the range `A1:C3`. Only positive numbers will be formatted (negative numbers and 0 remain unchanged).
In the standard module, put the function code:

```
Function FeetIn(data As Double) As String
   Dim ft As Long, inch As Double
   ft = Int(data / 12)
   inch = data - 12 * ft
   FeetIn = IIf(ft >= 1, ft & "' ", vbNullString) & _
            IIf(inch > 0, inch & "''", vbNullString)       ' two apostrophes
End Function
```

In the sheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Set Target = Intersect(Target, Range("A1:C3"))
   If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In Target
      If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
         cell.NumberFormat = """" & FeetIn(cell.Value) & """;-General;0;@"
      Else
         cell.NumberFormat = "General"
      End If
   Next cell
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image: Feet_Inch]

Answer (score 0):

Formatting without a formula requires using a built-in format.

Excel does have a format for displaying in feet and inches, where the feet
number is before the point and the inches are in the decimal part.

Use "Format Cells...", Category "Custom", and enter the following format
specification: `0' 0\"`. Modify this format as required.

That's the most you can do with Excel formatting. More than that require
a formula that can only be used with an extra column.

For more information see
[Excel custom number formats](https://exceljet.net/articles/custom-number-formats).

Comment: For what it is worth: LibreOffice displays `6' 2"` for a value of 62, when using `0' 0\"` as User defined formatting code.